# Can I use java.net.Socket to download http content(image, mp3 file and other)?

Tags: android

I am a begginer in java/android. My question is:
Can I download image(mp3 or other http contents) from http site using java.net.Socket? I am going to create several parallel threads for downloading the same contents.When one(thread) of them takes time more MAX time, supervisor interupts it and start againg.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use java.net.socket?

You can use **org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient**.

Which is easy to implement I think.

Comment: Hi.It is a goal of my tast to use socket instead of DefaultHttpClient.